# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[NavbarComponent -> NavbarComponent

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I am trying to make a login with google Auth on Firebase and when I login and try to load another component or a page I get the following. I have been trying to fix this bug for a whole day now and am very fed up. If anyone could help it would be appreciated.

My entire project is public at https://github.com/domilx/ProjetBocal-Angular

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[NavbarComponent -> NavbarComponent -> NavbarComponent]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for NavbarComponent!
get@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:120414:27
```

**Here is my code**

**Navbar.component.html:**

```html
<div mat-elevation-z4>
  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <button routerLink="dashboard" mat-button aria-label="Home">
      <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
      Projet Bocal
    </button>

    <span class="spacer-1"></span>

    <button mat-button aria-label="Classroom">
      <mat-icon>class</mat-icon>
      Classroom
    </button>

    <button mat-button aria-label="Links">
      <mat-icon>links</mat-icon>
      Links
    </button>

    <span class="spacer-1"></span>

    <button mat-button aria-label="Logout" *ngIf="auth.user$ | async as user" (click)="auth.signOut()">
      <mat-icon>exit_to_app</mat-icon>
      Logout, {{ user.displayName }}
    </button>
    <span class="spacer"></span>

    <button routerLink="settings" mat-icon-button aria-label="settings" *ngIf="auth.user$ | async as user">
      <mat-icon>settings</mat-icon>
    </button>

  </mat-toolbar>
</div>
```

**Auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from './user.model';
import { AngularFireAuth }  from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {
  user$: Observable<User | null | undefined>;
  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private router: Router,
  ) {
    this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        if (user) {
          return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
        } else {
          return of(null);
        }
      })
    );
  }

  async googleSignin() {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    const credential = await this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(provider);
    return this.updateUserData(credential.user);
  }

  async signOut() {
    await this.afAuth.signOut();
    return this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }

  private updateUserData(user) {
    // Sets user data to firestore on login
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<User> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);

    const data = {
      uid: user.uid,
      email: user.email,
      displayName: user.displayName,
      photoURL: user.photoURL
    };

    return userRef.set(data, { merge: true });

  }
}
```

**Auth.guard.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  CanActivate,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
  Router
} from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { tap, map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(next, state): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.auth.user$.pipe(
      take(1),
      map(user => !!user), // <-- map to boolean
      tap(loggedIn => {
        if (!loggedIn) {
          console.log('access denied');
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

**App.module.ts**

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getAuth, provideAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore/';
import { getFirestore, provideFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/pages/about/about.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './components/pages/contact/contact.component';
import { ClassroomComponent } from './components/pages/dashboard/classroom/classroom.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/pages/dashboard/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { LinksComponent } from './components/pages/dashboard/links/links.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/pages/home/home.component';
import { SettingsComponent } from './components/pages/settings/settings.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/shared/footer/footer.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/shared/navbar/navbar.component';
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
import { AuthGuard } from './services/auth.guard';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    SettingsComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ClassroomComponent,
    LinksComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule,
    MaterialModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),

  ],
  providers: [
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AuthGuard,
    AuthService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**App-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { SettingsComponent } from './components/pages/settings/settings.component';
import { AboutComponent} from './components/pages/about/about.component';
import { ContactComponent} from './components/pages/contact/contact.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/pages/dashboard/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/pages/home/home.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './services/auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'', component:HomeComponent},
  {path:'settings', component:SettingsComponent,  canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  {path:'home', redirectTo:'/', pathMatch:'full'},
  {path:'about', component:AboutComponent,  canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  {path:'contact', component:ContactComponent,  canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  {path:'dashboard', component:DashboardComponent,  canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
];
  @NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
  })
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**navbar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../../../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public auth: AuthService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Comment: can you post your AppModule code as well?

Comment: Sure i'll edit it now

Comment: thanks, one last thing. can you also include your AppRoutingModule?

Comment: Done! I added it at the bottom

Comment: thanks, sorry i keep asking for additional code, can you also add your navbar component ts code?

Comment: It's all good! Ill add it

Comment: ok I think we can rule out any issues with the component itself. This error has to do with dependency injection. I found a similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47516090/no-provider-for-simple-component. 

See if there's any other components or services that inject or reference NavbarComponent (search your codebase for 'NavbarComponent' and see what comes up).

While youre at it, double check your imports & providers in AppModule. The first 4 lines in providers should be in imports instead of in providers

Comment: Thank you so much! I found the issue and I will be posting it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue..
In my dashboard.component.ts I had imported the NavBar for test a long while ago and forgot to remove it:

```
import { NavbarComponent } from './../../../shared/navbar/navbar.component';
import { Component, OnInit,EventEmitter,Output } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../../../../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() isLogout = new EventEmitter<void>()
  constructor(NavbarComponent : NavbarComponent, public auth: AuthService) { }


  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

Just had to remove

```
NavbarComponent : NavbarComponent
```